# What is the format of a good motivation letter?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am writing a motivation letter to be used in applying for masters from German or Finnish Universities. I have the following points explained in my motivation letter:

- How I see this technical world
- Why I chose Computer Science in my undergraduate
- What I learned in undergraduate
- What are my interests
- Why I want to pursue Masters
- Why I chose their University

What could be the format of a good motivation letter?

What other points could be included to make it better at explaining myself? And how to arrange those points? How to connect a motivation letter to your CV?

Comment: do you perhaps mean that you're writing a  Statement of Purpose ?

Comment: Hey! I don't know what your native language is, but in mine, what you want is literally called a _Motivation letter_, but last year when I had to write one, I realized that a proper English term is a _cover letter_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, just typing "motivation letter" or "cover letter" into Google seems to spew up links to loads of hints, tips, and how-to-s, so I guess it's not so hard to find materials outside of here.

So, instead, I'll focus on the advice that was given to me last year when I had to write one, since it worked for me :)

An important thing to realize is that a *cover letter* is supposed to **complement your resume, not duplicate the same information**. Thus, your qualifications and achievements should mostly stay in the CV.

Also, you should **focus** mostly **on the position you are applying for, what makes you want it and what makes you think you would be good for it**, which means that *"how I see this technical world"* probably does not deserve much elaboration (one sentence should be okay in my opinion). You are trying to convince them that **you are the One** and show them what makes you different from the bulk of people applying. What makes you more suited, more likely to succeed, or a better fit than other applications they're considering. (I would guess it's easier for a Master studies application since they will be admitting more than one/a handful of students).

Finally, the structure that I used, and will probably use the next time I will have to write something like that, is **dividing the letter in to three parts**:

- **you:** here's where you'll put information on you. While you're not supposed to list *all* your achievements here, you should emphasize or elaborate on specific achievements, skills and motivations that make you especially suited *for the position you're applying for*
- **them:** it is important to "prove" that you're not sending out generic application letters. You demonstrate that you're familiar with the work done in the university/lab/research group you are applying for.

  If you're applying as a PhD student to a lab/professor, you might want to mention a specific paper or project and write an intelligible sentence or two about that. If you're applying for a University, you might want to pick some specific of their programme that especially caught your eye.
- **you and them together:** first section is about how awesome you are. The second, how awesome *they* are. Now (to conclude), you have to show why you thing *you would be awesome with them*. Why do you think you're a good fit, right there? This section is *not only* about what they can do for you, you also have to try and convince then of *how they can benefit from you*.

Finally, the letter should **not be longer than one page**. Somewhere, you can even find this as a hard limit on an application. In my experience, you should also not have more than 3 sections. I managed to put an introductory sentence and an finishing sentence just fine in the "sections" I mentioned. Also, **your writing should be impeccable.** If you can, get a native English speaker to check your language. Use a spell checker. **Pay attention to details**. Getting an address wrong, or a letter in a name, shows sloppiness. Maybe it does not consciously affect the decision, but it might on some level.

And the last advice I got, which I did follow, but you *don't have to take it as a hard rule*: **avoid negative statements**. It's supposed to give a better tone to your letter. So, instead of saying, e.g. "Unfortunately, I couldn't find and internship during my last summer", you should write something like "Having a free summer before my last year, it allowed me to spend more time reading upon the areas of my choosing". The positive statements should help you present the facts in a more positive light.

Answer (score 0):

I can talk to you by my own personal experience following a Master´s in a Finnish university (about the German case I am ignorant about that). Anyway Finns are very laconic people, try to submit your motivation letter as concise and direct as possible. I have taken a look at the questions that you are plan to answer in your motivation letter and they are just fine.

In my case I submitted my CV separated from the motivation letter, but a big plus would it be to show that you have some sort of research experience; for example if you have made some research article during your undergraduate or you have been a research assistant. In case that you do not have that, you can express your interest directly to make research in the field that you are applying for your master´s degree (I think that you have covered that part also in your questions stated before)

Good luck!