# What to include in a motivational letter for research grant?

Tags: application, funding

I was thinking of what would one include in a motivational letter for a Phd grant/scholarship at the cross-section between mathematics and economics?

I have no experience in processes of this kind, even though I'm getting a bit old for this. =D

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am hoping the question [A good motivation letter](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13574/546) would be helpful to you.